# Set Constraints Programatically Of An XIB File in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, xib

How to Attach XIB File at the buttom of Super view

I Have an XIB File Named "xibFIleView"

[image]

My code for calling XIB View is:-

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       self.view.addSubview(instanceFromNib())
    }

    func instanceFromNib() -> xibFIleView {

        return UINib(nibName: "xibFileView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! xibFIleView
    }
}
```

When I run My project my Simulator shows:-
[image]

How Can We Attach XIB view at the Bottom of the super view.

Comment: Did you try solution that I posted?

Comment: yes it works for me thanks @Bhaumik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting `constraints` or `frame` to your `xibView`.

**Set Constraints:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let xibView = instanceFromNib()
    self.view.addSubview(xibView)
    xibView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let constraint_leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: xibView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let constraint_bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: xibView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let constraint_height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: xibView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: xibView.frame.height)
    let constraint_width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: xibView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: xibView.frame.width)
    self.view.addConstraint(constraint_leading)
    self.view.addConstraint(constraint_bottom)
    xibView.addConstraint(constraint_height)
    xibView.addConstraint(constraint_width)
}
```

**----- or -----**

**Set frame:**

Make following changes in your `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let xibView = instanceFromNib()
    let y_pos = self.view.frame.height - xibView.frame.height
    xibView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y_pos, width: xibView.frame.width, height: xibView.frame.height)
    // change x, y, width, height based on your requirement.
    self.view.addSubview(xibView)
}
```

Note: change x, y position and width, height based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use auto layout to add 4 constraints sufficient to specify the subviews width, height, x and y position.  For example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let child = instanceFromNib()
    self.view.addSubview(child)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        child.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        child.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        child.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        child.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300) // <- Your desired view height here
    )]
}

func instanceFromNib() -> xibFIleView {

    return UINib(nibName: "xibFileView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! xibFIleView
}
```